# Dependency injection in TypeScript

Tags: tdd, requirejs, typescript, amd

I'm looking into the possibilities to do TDD with TypeScript.
If I write my tests in TypeScript, is it possible to make the import statements return mocks for my class under test?
Or is the only feasible approach to write the tests in pure javascript and deal with injecting AMDs myself?

Answer (score 23):

I have developed an IoC container called InversifyJS with advanced dependency injection features like contextual bindings.

You need to follow *3 basic steps* to use it:

#### 1. Add annotations

The annotation API is based on Angular 2.0:

```
import { injectable, inject } from "inversify";

@injectable()
class Katana implements IKatana {
    public hit() {
        return "cut!";
    }
}

@injectable()
class Shuriken implements IShuriken {
    public throw() {
        return "hit!";
    }
}

@injectable()
class Ninja implements INinja {

    private _katana: IKatana;
    private _shuriken: IShuriken;

    public constructor(
        @inject("IKatana") katana: IKatana,
        @inject("IShuriken") shuriken: IShuriken
    ) {
        this._katana = katana;
        this._shuriken = shuriken;
    }

    public fight() { return this._katana.hit(); };
    public sneak() { return this._shuriken.throw(); };

}
```

#### 2. Declare bindings

The binding API is based on Ninject:

```
import { Kernel } from "inversify";

import { Ninja } from "./entities/ninja";
import { Katana } from "./entities/katana";
import { Shuriken} from "./entities/shuriken";

var kernel = new Kernel();
kernel.bind<INinja>("INinja").to(Ninja);
kernel.bind<IKatana>("IKatana").to(Katana);
kernel.bind<IShuriken>("IShuriken").to(Shuriken);

export default kernel;
```

#### 3. Resolve dependencies

The resolution API is based on Ninject:

```
import kernel = from "./inversify.config";

var ninja = kernel.get<INinja>("INinja");

expect(ninja.fight()).eql("cut!"); // true
expect(ninja.sneak()).eql("hit!"); // true
```

The latest release (2.0.0) supports many use cases:

- Kernel modules
- Kernel middleware
- Use classes, string literals or Symbols as dependency identifiers
- Injection of constant values
- Injection of class constructors
- Injection of factories
- Auto factory
- Injection of providers (async factory)
- Activation handlers (used to inject proxies)
- Multi injections
- Tagged bindings
- Custom tag decorators
- Named bindings
- Contextual bindings
- Friendly exceptions (e.g. Circular dependencies)

You can learn more about it at https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS

Answer (score 21):

I use [infuse.js](https://github.com/soundstep/infuse.js) for Dependency Injection in TypeScript.

#### Reference the d.ts

```
/// <reference path="definition/infusejs/infusejs.d.ts"/>
```

#### Initialize your injector at startup

```
this.injector = new infuse.Injector();
```

#### Map Dependencies

```
this.injector.mapClass( 'TodoController', TodoController );
this.injector.mapClass( 'TodoView', TodoView );
this.injector.mapClass( 'TodoModel', TodoModel, true );  // 'true' Map as singleton
```

#### Inject Dependencies

```
export class TodoController
{
    static inject = ['TodoView', 'TodoModel'];

    constructor( todoView:TodoView, todoModel:TodoModel )
    {

    }
 }
```

It's string based as opposed to being type based (as reflection isn't yet possible in TypeScript). Despite that, it works very well in my applications.

Comment: As per the [discussion here](https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/401501), reflection is not likely to ever make an appearance in Typescript.

Answer (score 6):

Try this [Dependency Injector (Typejector)](http://olegdokuka.github.io/Typejector/)

GitHub [Typejector](https://github.com/OlegDokuka/Typejector)

With new TypeScript 1.5 it is possible using annotation way

For example

```
    @injection
    class SingletonClass {
        public cat: string = "Kitty";
        public dog: string = "Hot";

        public say() {
            alert(`${this.cat}-Cat and ${this.dog}-Dog`);
        }
    }
    @injection
    class SimpleClass {
        public say(something: string) {
            alert(`You said ${something}?`);
        }
    }

    @resolve
    class NeedInjectionsClass {
        @inject(SingletonClass)
        public helper: SingletonClass;
        @inject(SimpleClass)
        public simpleHelper: SimpleClass;

        constructor() {
            this.helper.say();
            this.simpleHelper.say("wow");
        }
    }
    class ChildClass extends NeedInjectionsClass {

    }

    var needInjection = new ChildClass();
```

For question case:
some property should realise pseudo Interface (or abstract class) like in next example.

```
    class InterfaceClass {
        public cat: string;
        public dog: string;

        public say() {

        }
    }

    @injection(true, InterfaceClass)
    class SingletonClass extends InterfaceClass {
        public cat: string = "Kitty";
        public dog: string = "Hot";

        public say() {
            alert(`${this.cat}-Cat and ${this.dog}-Dog`);
        }
    }

    @injection(true, InterfaceClass)
    class MockInterfaceClass extends InterfaceClass {
        public cat: string = "Kitty";
        public dog: string = "Hot";

        public say() {
            alert(`Mock-${this.cat}-Cat and Mock-${this.dog}-Dog`);
        }
    }

    @injection
    class SimpleClass {
        public say(something: string) {
            alert(`You said ${something}?`);
        }
    }

    @resolve
    class NeedInjectionsClass {
        @inject(InterfaceClass)
        public helper: InterfaceClass;
        @inject(SimpleClass)
        public simpleHelper: SimpleClass;

        constructor() {
            this.helper.say();
            this.simpleHelper.say("wow");
        }
    }

    class ChildClass extends NeedInjectionsClass {

    }

    var needInjection = new ChildClass();
```

**Note:** *Mock injection should define after source code, because it mast redefine class-creator for interface*

Comment: Project is no longer supported for those looking into it

Answer (score 2):

For people who use Angular2 I have developed Fluency Injection https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluency-injection. The documentation is quite complete and it mimics the behaviour of Angular2's DI.

Feedback is much appreciated and I hope it helps you :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the solution:
[Lightweight dependency injection container for JavaScript/TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe)

```
import {autoInjectable, container} from "tsyringe";

class MyService {
  move(){
    console.log('myService move 123', );
  }
}

class MyServiceMock {
  move(){
    console.log('mock myService move 777', );
  }
}

@autoInjectable()
export class ClassA {
  constructor(public service?: MyService) {
  }
  move(){
    this.service?.move();
  }
}

container.register(MyService, {
  useClass: MyServiceMock
});

new ClassA().move();
```

output:

> mock myService move 777

Answer (score 1):

I've been developing a DI solution called [Pigly](https://github.com/pigly-di/pigly). An example given the original question regarding injecting and testing (admittedly not automatic-mock generation - although you could try [ts-auto-mock](https://github.com/uittorio/ts-auto-mock#readme) [as I've done here](https://github.com/pigly-di/pigly/blob/develop/packages/pigly-example/example-mock.ts)):

Given:

```
interface IDb {
  set(key: string, value: string);
}

interface IApi {
  setName(name: string);
}

class Api implements IApi {
  constructor(private db: IDb) {}
  setName(name: string){
    this.db.set("name", name);
  }
}
```

We can bind the types with,

```
import { Kernel, toSelf, to, toConst } from 'pigly';
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

let spy = sinon.spy();

let kernel = new Kernel();

kernel.bind(toSelf(Api));
kernel.bind<IApi>(to<Api>());
kernel.bind<IDb>(toConst({ set: spy }));
```

then resolve and test with:

```
let api = kernel.get<IApi>();

api.setName("John");

console.log(spy.calledWith("name", "John"));
```

execution/compilation of this example requires a typescript transformer - to compile the interface-symbols and constructor provider into plain javascript. [There are a few ways to do this](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript#how-to-install). The ts-node + ttypescript approach is to have a tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "plugins": [{
      "transform": "@pigly/transformer"
    }]
  }
}
```

and execute with

```
ts-node --compiler ttypescript example-mock.ts
```

Pigly has the distinction of not requiring any changes to your (or third-party) classes, at the expense of either the use of a typescript transformer, or more verbose binding if (you don't want to use the transformer). Its still experimental, but I think it shows promise.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript works well with AMD loaders like requirejs. If confgured properly, TypeScript will output fully AMD compliant javascript.

In a testing situation, you could configure requirejs to inject testable modules.

Comment: But is there a way to do that injection without stepping outside of my TypeScript bubble?

Comment: Depends on what you mean, I guess...  Every bit of "javascript" in my application that I generated from TypeScript that I wrote. The goal for most of my applications these days is to use only TypeScript. But I don't exactly know what you're asking here.

Comment: Ok, I was a little bit unclear there. I'm trying to wrap my head around the duality of JS and TS.
Suppose I have a class B taking in a module A:
import A = module('/path/to/A');
class B {
// methods using A
}
Is it possible to provide a mock for module A while still letting the test be in TypeScript with full code completion?

Comment: Currently, for pure JS, I'm using Jasmine + RequireJS with Sinon for the mocks.

Comment: I've come to realize that dependency injection in TS differs from JS when you want the tests in TS also. Then the preferred way would be to inject through the constructor instead of "through" define/import.
Then the question left is how I can keep my tests in a different place and still have the module paths valid both during runtime (RequireJS) and compile time (for type checking). Should I write a new question for that?

Comment: I use requirejs.config to trick requirejs into loading the correct modules at runtime when the TS paths don't necessarily match up with the paths that requirejs is looking for... Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I do that too. Runtime is no problem, compile time is. What do I do for TS when the module paths do not match up with my file system?

Comment: I'm confused as to why your problem isn't the other way around. For me, compile time is no problem and run time requires hefty fiddling with requirejs.config.  It was hard for me to grasp, but the TS design time and JS run time are completely separate things. TS cares nothing about JS and JS cares nothing about TS.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a shot: https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-injectionjs. It is a generic use dependency injection package.

@EasySingleton creates a single instance of the dependency through the entire application. It is ideal for a service of some sort.

@EasyPrototype creates as many instances of the dependency as needed. It is ideal for changeable dependencies.

@EasyFactory is primarily used for inheritance:

You can do anything using this package:
Simple usage (Coming from the readme):

```
import { Easy, EasyFactory, EasyPrototype, EasySingleton } from 'easy-injectionjs';

@EasyFactory()
abstract class Person {
  abstract getName();
  abstract setName(v: string);
}

// @EasyObservable()
@EasySingleton()
class Somebody extends Person{
  // @Easy()
  constructor (private name: string) {
    super()
    this.name = 'Sal';
  }

  public getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  public setName(v: string) {
    this.name = v;
  }
}

@EasyPrototype()
class Nobody extends Person{
  @Easy()
  somebody: Person;
  constructor () {
    super()
  }

  public getName() {
    return this.somebody.getName();
  }

  public setName(v: string) {
    this.somebody.setName(v);
  }
}

@EasyPrototype()
class Data {
  @Easy()
  somebody: Person;
  name: string;

  change(v: string) {
    this.somebody.setName(v);
  }

  getName(): string {
    return this.somebody.getName();
  }
}

let n = new Nobody();
console.log(n.getName()) // Prints Sal
n.setName('awesome');
console.log(n.getName())  // Prints awesome
let d = new Data()
console.log(d.getName())  // Prints awesome
d.change('Gelba')
console.log(n.getName())  // Prints Gelba
d.change('kaa')
console.log(n.getName())  // Prints Kaa
```

Even if you want to inject node modules you can do this:

```
import * as IExpress from 'express';
import { Easy, EasySingleton } from 'easy-injectionjs';

@EasySingleton()
class Express extends IExpress {} 

@EasySingleton()
export class App {
  @Easy()
  private _express: Express;
}

let app = new App();
console.log(app)
```

Of course, the usage of the express server isn't for console logging. It is just for testing :D.

Hope that helps :D

Answer (score 0):

[Dime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@coined/dime) is a very simple dependency injection library. It's very early into development, though, so it probably has some bugs. There is more information on the [wiki page](https://github.com/Anut-py/dime/wiki).

Example usage:

```
import { ItemsService } from './items-service'; // ItemsService is an interface
import { Inject } from '@coined/dime';

class ItemsWidget {
    @Inject()
    private itemsService: ItemsService;

    render() {
        this.itemsService.getItems().subscribe(items => {
            // ...
        });
    }
}

// Setup
const appPackage = new Package("App", {
    token: "itemsService",
    provideClass: AmazonItemsService // AmazonItemsService implements ItemsService
});

Dime.mountPackages(appPackage);

// Display the widget
const widget = new ItemsWidget();
widget.render();
```

Answer (score -6):

I work on AutoFixtureTS that is inspired by AutoFixture. AutoFixtureTS makes it easier for TypeScript developers to do Test-Driven Development by automating non-relevant Test Fixture Setup, allowing the Test Developer to focus on the essentials of each test case.

http://ronniehegelund.github.io/AutoFixtureTS/

Its still just prototype code, but check it out :-)

/ronnie